# Deploying rails 4 app on cpanel hostgator ssh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ssh, cpanel

I am using Ubuntu and I am getting stuck connecting to remote hostgator server. I am using ssh command terminal instead of the recommended puTTY for windows. I ran ssh `ssh username@hostname` but got `ssh: connect to host #####.co.uk port 22: Connection timed out` Maybe I am unclear what hostname is? I am entering a domain name associated with my hosting account for hostname and my cpanel username for username? Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem you may be having is that you have to specify a port 2222 argument for Hostgator.

So something like:

```
ssh username@hostname -p 2222
```

see http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/how-do-i-get-and-use-ssh-access